# Подскажите пожалуйста, что означает скобка после знака суммы?

Tags: математика, формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Полный пример из учебника]

Понятно, что это разбор того, как получается такая производная. Есть предположение, что это какой-то вектор. Но если это так, тогда не понятно откуда он берется и как [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

становится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Биноминальный коэффициент [здесь почитайте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Answer (score 3):

Обозначение, зависящее от школы :)

В русскоязычной литературе для обозначения количества сочетаний по *m* элементов из *n* (или, что то же самое, *биномиального коэффициента*) обычно используется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В англоязычной литературе (а в последнее время и у нас) то же самое обозначается как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в рядах, эквивалент без скобок я не встречал ни в России, ни за ее пределами. В статистике и теории вероятности встречал обе записи и там и там) все равно +

Comment: @Dmitry Вам сфотографировать соответствующие страницы математических книг?

Comment: Да, нет, конечно. Это не имеет большого смысла, если в принципе понимаешь о чем речь. Я больше про свой опыт.

Comment: @Dmitry Ну, весь мой опыт бунтует как раз против скобок. Если приходится что-то делать — переписываю через C_n^m, тогда работать можно :)